# Convert Text to Image in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, imageview

I want to convert text to image in kotlin.

**i.e.** i have text like this ***"Android kotlin"***

and i want output like this ***A K***

i got about output(code is below for *A K*) but i want to convert that output in to image.

```
 val initials = menuList.get(position).menuName
        .split(' ')
        .mapNotNull { it.firstOrNull()?.toString() }
        .reduce { acc, s -> acc + s }
```

i knew this option directly set that text to TextView and also set background to textview but i want to convert that text to image and set it to image view.

Any other option for same  in **KOTLIN**?

Comment: First you need to cut off the text which you want to convert to image. Cut the first letters of each word.You can do it for example by using `yourText.split(" ")`, and then taking first letters of each element of resulting array. Then when you have the right text, you have to draw it on the image first. After that you set that image into `ImageView`

Comment: You can draw text on `Canvas` by either calling `drawText` or with `StaticLayout`